# How to know the Galois Group of a polynomial is a solvable group?

Tags: polynomials, group-theory

```
ResourceFunction["StauduharGaloisGroup"][2 x^5+3 x^4+10 x^3+15 x^2+8 x+12,x]["GaloisGroup"]
```

> `DihedralGroup[5]`

We can use `FiniteGroupData` like this:

```
FiniteGroupData[{"DihedralGroup", 5}, "Solvable"]
```

> `True`

But the `FiniteGroupData` cannot deal with the `PermutationGroup` like:

```
 g = ResourceFunction["StauduharGaloisGroup"][
   5 + 14 x + 15 x^2 + 5 x^3 + x^5, x]["GaloisGroup"]
```

> `PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2,3,5,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,4,5}}]}]`

So how to judge the group `g` is a **solvable group** or not?

Comment: I might use [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/421#4446) on the [Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), but I don't know if there's an API you could use to call from Mathematica.  Sorry if this isn't helpful. (BTW, your second example factors over the rational into a linear + quartic, so it's solvable, which `Solve[5 + 14 x + 15 x^2 + 5 x^3 + x^5 == 0] // ToRadicals` also shows.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 `2 x^5 + 7 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 2 x + 1` is also solvable, but `ToRadicals[Solve[2 x^5 + 7 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]]` don't work again...

Comment: The docs say `ToRadicals` does not always work.

Comment: [Magma code & radical extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikqhd.jpg), fwiw.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/) also [can do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O9it.png), but I hope to know how to do it by *MMA*

Comment: I don't think Mathematica has routine to do that. Maybe someone has written one. I once asked a mathematician, who replied, "Use Magma," but that was a decade ago. This paper contains an algorithm if you're interested in doing it yourself: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/Papers/LaMi85.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check the *Derived Series* and the last one equal to `PermutationGroup[{}]`(we use the function `delCyc` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268708/21532)):

```
delCyc[g_] := Module[{t = GroupGenerators[g], tmp}, 
  If[PermutationGroup[t] == PermutationGroup[tmp = DeleteCases[t, #]],t=tmp]&/@t;
  PermutationGroup[t]]

commutator[a_,b_]:=PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[a],InversePermutation[b],a,b]

DerivedGroup[G_] := Module[{lis}, 
  If[G === PermutationGroup[{}], Return[PermutationGroup[{}]]];
  delCyc[PermutationGroup[
    DeleteDuplicates[commutator @@@ Subsets[GroupElements[G], {2}]]]]]

Most[FixedPointList[DerivedGroup, G, SameTest -> Equal]]
```

> {PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2,3,5,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,4,5}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2,3,4,5}}]}],PermutationGroup[{}]}

Then the group `G` is a solvable group indeed. But it seem this method just can deal the groups of relatively small order.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment:

The group:

```
p = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2, 3, 5, 4}}], 
Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]}];
```

has elements: `g = GroupElements[p]`:

> {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 3, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 4, 5, 3}}],
> Cycles[{{2, 5}, {3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 5}}],   Cycles[{{1, 2,
> 3, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}],   Cycles[{{1, 2, 5, 4}}],
> Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}],   Cycles[{{1, 3}, {4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 5,
> 2, 4}}],   Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 5, 2}}],
> Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}],   Cycles[{{1, 4, 2,
> 5, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 5, 4, 3, 2}}],   Cycles[{{1, 5, 3, 4}}],
> Cycles[{{1, 5, 2, 3}}],   Cycles[{{1, 5}, {2, 4}}]}

It is of order 20 (`Length[g]`). This is enough to establish it is solvable. See [here](https://yutsumura.com/a-group-of-order-20-is-solvable/#:%7E:text=Therefore%20the%20group%20G%20of,G%20is%20a%20solvable%20group.)

Mathematica can  provide insight into this. $C_5$ is a subgroup of `p`:

```
c5 = GroupElements[CyclicGroup[5]];
in = Intersection[g, c5]
```

Further, it is a normal subgroup:

```
conj[x_] := PermutationProduct[#, x, InversePermutation[#]] & /@ g
Flatten[conj /@ c5] // Union
```

yields:

> {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}}],
> Cycles[{{1, 4, 2, 5, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 5, 4, 3, 2}}]}

which establishes $g H g^{-1}=H$, where $H=C_5$.

Further,
"p/C_5" is Abelian can be shown (conveniently from this example) by showing quotient group elements commute:

```
cos = {a, b, c, d} = 
  Union[RightCosetRepresentative[CyclicGroup[5], #] & /@ g]
su = Subsets[cos, {2}]
sur = Reverse /@ su
PermutationProduct @@@ su
PermutationProduct @@@ sur
```

yields:

> {Cycles[{{2, 3, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 4, 5, 3}}],   Cycles[{{2, 5}, {3,
> 4}}], Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 4, 5, 3}}],   Cycles[{{2, 3, 5, 4}}]}
>
> {Cycles[{{2, 3, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 4, 5, 3}}],   Cycles[{{2, 5}, {3,
> 4}}], Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 4, 5, 3}}],   Cycles[{{2, 3, 5, 4}}]}

As $\lhd C_5\lhd$ p: and the p/$C_5$ and $C_5/<e>$ are Abelian, p is solvable.

Comment: There is a resource function `ResourceFunction["SubgroupQ"][CyclicGroup[5], p]` do this

Comment: Thanks. Did not know this.

Comment: You seem to have learned Group Theory very well, but it seems to be a way to determine a specified group only. (MMA can't even tell if a group is an abelian group

Comment: @yode I am also trying to learn what can and can’t be done with MMA. A lot of brute force here to provide insights. Fortunately, the Sylow theorems etc can make life easier…

Comment: As far as I know, Sylow theorems cannot be used to determine whether the group is solvable or not?

Comment: Yes, but in this particular example of group of order 20: n_5=1 => group of order 5 and normal etc etc

Comment: I note you use `RightCosetRepresentative` to get quotient group, but the quotient group is not unique as I know.

Comment: As normal subgroup the right and left cosets are the same. There are quotient group is of order 4: so really didn’t need to do this as is necessarily Abelian. It was some degree of luck (I alluded to this in text)  that the representative multiplications turned out to show commutativity. I am sure there are better ways. As I wrote it was a comment to provide insights.

Comment: Done......... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is also a comment extension, maybe it can give some clue for the question.

---

After I `` DownValues[DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`RawFiniteGroupData] `` I will get:

```
HoldPattern[
  DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`RawFiniteGroupData[
   DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`group_, Solvable]] :> 
 Block[{DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`res}, 
  DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`res = 
   DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`RawFiniteGroupData[
    DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`group, Order]; 
  True /; DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`validQ[
     DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`res] && 
    OddQ[DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`res]]
```

And `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal[DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`validQ] `` will get:

```
validQ[expr_] := And[UnsameQ[expr, $Failed], UnsameQ[Head @ expr, Missing]];
validQ[___] := False;
```

This is a built-in algorithm for those named-group, we can use it like:

```
DataPaclets`FiniteGroupDataDump`RawFiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup",3},"Solvable"]
```

> True